# How to have records without keys show up in Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

UPDATED based on comment...

The first stock (ISIN) is the main one and the second is a benchmark (MNEMONIC) against which we measure the performance. As long as a benchmark exists my query works and returns results. However, when no benchmark exists (i.e. because it hasn't been determined yet), the query returns no results at all. How can i get it to show a result for the main stock (which always exists) under any circumstance?

Here is my current SQL:

```
PARAMETERS strISIN Text ( 255 );
SELECT 
    tblFUNDS.ISIN, tblFunds_TS_Data.Date, tblFunds_TS_Data.Price, tblBM_Data.MNEMONIC, 
    tblBM_TS_Data.Date, tblBM_TS_Data.Price, RiskFreeReturn.F6 AS RiskFreeReturn_USD, 
    tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection
FROM 
    ((((tblFUNDS LEFT OUTER JOIN tblFunds_Data ON tblFUNDS.ISIN = tblFunds_Data.ISIN) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblFunds_TS_Data ON tblFunds_Data.ISIN = tblFunds_TS_Data.ISIN) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblBM_Data ON tblFUNDS.DS_Benchmark_Symbol = tblBM_Data.MNEMONIC) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblBM_TS_Data ON tblBM_Data.MNEMONIC = tblBM_TS_Data.MNEMONIC) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN RiskFreeReturn ON tblFunds_TS_Data.Date = RiskFreeReturn.F1
WHERE 
    (((tblFUNDS.ISIN)=[strISIN]) 
    AND ((tblFunds_TS_Data.Date)=[tblBM_TS_Data].[Date] 
        And (tblFunds_TS_Data.Date)>=#12/28/2013#) 
    AND ((tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection)=0))
ORDER BY tblFunds_TS_Data.Date;
```

Comment: Use `left outer join` in the part that joins based in `mnemonic`

Comment: I added a LEFT OUTER JOIN as you suggested but it didn't work in getting the records to show up: `  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblBM_Data ON tblFUNDS.DS_Benchmark_Symbol = tblBM_Data.MNEMONIC) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblBM_TS_Data ON tblBM_Data.MNEMONIC = tblBM_TS_Data.MNEMONIC) `

Comment: `And (tblFunds_TS_Data.Date)>=#12/28/2013#` -- you can't have WHERE criteria for tables on the OUTER side of joins. Or at least you need `OR ... IS NULL`.

Comment: @Andre Thank you! That worked... I changed it to be: WHERE (((tblFUNDS.ISIN)=[strISIN]) AND ((tblFunds_TS_Data.Date)=[tblBM_TS_Data].[Date] And (tblFunds_TS_Data.Date)>=#12/28/2013# Or [tblBM_TS_Data].[Date] Is Null) AND ((tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection)=0))

Comment: @Andre Please leave it as an answer so that I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with this WHERE criteria on a table on the OUTER side of the LEFT JOIN:

```
And tblFunds_TS_Data.Date >= #12/28/2013#
```

To filter on this table, you need to add `OR ... IS NULL`, so the query can still include the records where the OUTER side is empty:

```
And (tblFunds_TS_Data.Date >= #12/28/2013# OR tblFunds_TS_Data.Date IS NULL)
```